# Is there a way to add Python f-string support to Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: python, visual-studio, ide, f-string

I'm switching back to using VS2017 for most of my Python development after using VSCode for the majority of the time. In VSCode I was able to use f-strings nicely with syntax highlighting and intellisense.

In VS2017, when I use an f-string, it'll just display as a raw string without highlighting. This works when the program runs, but for debugging and writing, it makes things more of a pain.

Does anyone know if this can be added to VS2017? Both are running off of python 3.6 so I wouldn't think there should be an issue.

Just to clarify, I'm referring to these:

```
f'Hello My Name Is { user.Name }'
```